# Nvidia Driver Won't Load on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: driver, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, failed-installation

I am trying to install NVIDIA Driver for Titan Xp. I type the following for installation:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-418
```

The installation runs with no errors. However, after rebooting the driver is not loaded. Here is the error that nvidia-smi command gives:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Here is the complete installation log (in the terminal):

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 cuda-command-line-tools-8-0 cuda-command-line-tools-9-0 cuda-command-line-tools-9-2 cuda-compiler-10-1 cuda-compiler-9-2
  cuda-core-8-0 cuda-core-9-0 cuda-cublas-8-0 cuda-cublas-9-0 cuda-cublas-9-2 cuda-cublas-dev-8-0 cuda-cublas-dev-9-0 cuda-cublas-dev-9-2 cuda-cudart-10-1
  cuda-cudart-8-0 cuda-cudart-9-0 cuda-cudart-9-2 cuda-cudart-dev-10-1 cuda-cudart-dev-8-0 cuda-cudart-dev-9-0 cuda-cudart-dev-9-2 cuda-cufft-10-1
  cuda-cufft-8-0 cuda-cufft-9-0 cuda-cufft-9-2 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1 cuda-cufft-dev-8-0 cuda-cufft-dev-9-0 cuda-cufft-dev-9-2 cuda-cuobjdump-10-1
  cuda-cuobjdump-9-2 cuda-cupti-10-1 cuda-cupti-9-2 cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-curand-8-0 cuda-curand-9-0 cuda-curand-9-2 cuda-curand-dev-10-1 cuda-curand-dev-8-0
  cuda-curand-dev-9-0 cuda-curand-dev-9-2 cuda-cusolver-10-1 cuda-cusolver-8-0 cuda-cusolver-9-0 cuda-cusolver-9-2 cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 cuda-cusolver-dev-8-0
  cuda-cusolver-dev-9-0 cuda-cusolver-dev-9-2 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-cusparse-8-0 cuda-cusparse-9-0 cuda-cusparse-9-2 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1
  cuda-cusparse-dev-8-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-9-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-9-2 cuda-documentation-10-1 cuda-documentation-8-0 cuda-documentation-9-0 cuda-documentation-9-2
  cuda-driver-dev-10-1 cuda-driver-dev-8-0 cuda-driver-dev-9-0 cuda-driver-dev-9-2 cuda-gdb-10-1 cuda-gdb-9-2 cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1
  cuda-gpu-library-advisor-9-2 cuda-libraries-10-1 cuda-libraries-9-0 cuda-libraries-9-2 cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 cuda-libraries-dev-9-0 cuda-libraries-dev-9-2
  cuda-license-10-1 cuda-license-8-0 cuda-license-9-0 cuda-license-9-2 cuda-memcheck-10-1 cuda-memcheck-9-2 cuda-misc-headers-10-1 cuda-misc-headers-8-0
  cuda-misc-headers-9-0 cuda-misc-headers-9-2 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-npp-8-0 cuda-npp-9-0 cuda-npp-9-2 cuda-npp-dev-10-1 cuda-npp-dev-8-0 cuda-npp-dev-9-0
  cuda-npp-dev-9-2 cuda-nsight-10-1 cuda-nsight-9-2 cuda-nsight-compute-10-1 cuda-nsight-systems-10-1 cuda-nvcc-10-1 cuda-nvcc-9-2 cuda-nvdisasm-10-1
  cuda-nvdisasm-9-2 cuda-nvgraph-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-8-0 cuda-nvgraph-9-0 cuda-nvgraph-9-2 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-dev-8-0 cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-0
  cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-2 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1 cuda-nvml-dev-10-1 cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 cuda-nvml-dev-9-0 cuda-nvml-dev-9-2 cuda-nvprof-10-1
  cuda-nvprof-9-2 cuda-nvprune-10-1 cuda-nvprune-9-2 cuda-nvrtc-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-8-0 cuda-nvrtc-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-9-2 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-8-0
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-2 cuda-nvtx-10-1 cuda-nvtx-9-2 cuda-nvvp-10-1 cuda-nvvp-9-2 cuda-samples-10-1 cuda-samples-8-0 cuda-samples-9-0
  cuda-samples-9-2 cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1 cuda-toolkit-10-1 cuda-toolkit-9-0 cuda-toolkit-9-2 cuda-tools-10-1 cuda-tools-9-2 cuda-visual-tools-10-1
  cuda-visual-tools-9-0 cuda-visual-tools-9-2 fonts-font-awesome fonts-lato fonts-mathjax freeglut3 freeglut3-dev ipython-notebook-common libcublas-dev
  libcublas10 libcublas7.5 libcudart7.5 libcufft7.5 libcufftw7.5 libcurand7.5 libcurl4-openssl-dev libcusolver7.5 libcusparse7.5 libjs-highlight
  libjs-highlight.js libjs-marked libjs-mathjax libjs-underscore libnppc7.5 libnppi7.5 libnpps7.5 libnvblas7.5 libnvrtc7.5 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm3
  libpython-all-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev libssl-doc libthrust-dev libvdpau-dev libvncserver1 libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxt-dev
  linux-headers-4.15.0-47 linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-50 linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-51
  linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-52 linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-51-generic linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-47-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-51-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-47-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-51-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-52-generic nsight-compute-2019.4.0 nsight-systems-2019.3.7 python-all python-all-dev python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python-pymysql
  python-wheel python3-wheel python3.5-dev ruby-did-you-mean ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit x11vnc-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-418 nvidia-opencl-icd-418 nvidia-prime
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuda1-304 nvidia-304 nvidia-current nvidia-opencl-icd-304
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-418 nvidia-418 nvidia-opencl-icd-418 nvidia-prime
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 4 to remove and 194 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/112 MB of archives.
After this operation, 314 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 940544 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libcuda1-304 (304.137-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-current (304.137-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-304 (304.137-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
INFO:Disable nvidia-304
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.137-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-70-generic
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-418.
(Reading database ... 940327 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-418_418.87.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-418 (418.87.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcuda1-418.
Preparing to unpack .../libcuda1-418_418.87.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcuda1-418 (418.87.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-opencl-icd-418.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-418_418.87.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-418 (418.87.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-prime_0.8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up nvidia-418 (418.87.01-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-418/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist/10_proprietary-graphics-drivers because associated file /usr/share/nvidia-418/nvidia-418.grub-gfxpayload (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-418/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-418/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-418/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-418/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

A modprobe blacklist file has been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent Nouveau from loading. This can be reverted by deleting /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf.
A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please replace /boot/initrd-4.15.0-70-generic with /boot/initrd-$(uname -r)-backup.

*****************************************************************************
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can   ***
*** be loaded.                                                            ***
*****************************************************************************

INFO:Enable nvidia-418
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 121) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 129) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 121) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/'.
Loading new nvidia-418-418.87.01 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.15.0-70-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-70-generic
Done.

nvidia_418:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_418_modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_418_drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_418_uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.........

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up libcuda1-418 (418.87.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-opencl-icd-418 (418.87.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-70-generic
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Mohammad, run `lsmod`, does it show you the driver?

Comment: Thanks for replying. "lsmod | grep nvidia" returns nothing.

Comment: Not good, try to run `sudo modprobe nvidia` (and for other drivers as well, if required). If that doesn't work check `ls /dev/nvidia*` or `lspci | grep nvidia -i`. Also try `sudo nvidia-smi`, `nvidia-smi` needs root to perform some tasks.

Comment: "sudo modprobe nvidia" returns: 

"modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_418': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)"

Comment: "ls /dev/nvidia*" returns "No such file or dir"

Comment: "lspci | grep nvidia -i" shows the hardware correctly.

Comment: "sudo nvidia-smi" returns "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

Comment: Looks like your device nodes are missing. You can add them manually, like somebody did here https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=238119, do you know how to proceed from here?

Comment: did you solve it ?